# Analytics API - multiple accounts

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to implement something like so:
There a multiple emails associated with analytics account:

```
john@gmail.com  http://john.com
dave@gmail.com  http://another.com
foo@gmail.com   http://foo.com
```

I need to fetch analytics data through API .
I am aware about credentials.json when creating app but what are my options to get done with multiple email accounts . 
**If I add mails as admins to one control mail is it possible to control all accounts with that email ?**

What is the best option to solve this issues.?

Thanks for reading

**EDIT 1**
To clarify I have web app which will show diff API  for different websites for each user 
Each user will have unique utm medium and they will see only their traffic . But I don't want to have multiple json files in application and send requests for each one , and as I understand I can create service account and add that email to all analytics accounts and it will do the trick right?

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to retrieve data from the API via a server-side script or application than the best option is to [create a service account](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/service-php) and add that to the respective Google Analytics properties.

If you are looking for a client-side solution you should add the same email to all the GA properties (as the client side APIs use the currently logged in user, so it would be difficult to switch between accounts). I assume that this is what you mean by "add mails as admins to one control mail".

Comment: Thanks @Eike for reply. 
Service account will do the trick right?
I can add analytics properties to service account and use only service account if I got you right .? IF so I think it is better then the second option

Comment: Service accounts have been specifically introduced by Google for this use case - they can authenticate against the API without a browser, so if  you want to run an application on a server to retrieve data then they are the way to go.

Comment: After looking at the updates it seems I misunderstood what  you want to do;  you can completely disregard my answer.

Comment: really ? I was about to try  as your answer was logical to this case.
one service account email which has access to all analytics accounts

Comment: It might be I still do not understand correctly.  You need a service account if you have a backend running on your server and the users do not have credentials for GA themselves. You do not need a service account if they log in with their existing accounts (with GA permissions) to a client-side app that merely visualizes the data.

Comment: users  - don't have permission to analytics account  , those are all ours(companies accounts) I need to use all accounts  to get data from each account and show in one website

Answer (score 0):

Credentials are associated with your application you can have as many users as you want authenticating to your application.   Assuming you save the refresh token for each user you can access their account when ever you like.

You could as stated in another answer use a service account however i would not do this unless you personally have control over all of these google Analytics accounts (the email addresses).   Using a service account you would have to have the owner of the account add the service account email address to their google analytics account for each analytics account that they want to grant you access to.    Then it will be your responsibility to ensure that user one does not have access to user twos data as the service account will not be able to see who owns what its going to have access to them all.   IMO the risk of showing the wrong data to the wrong user would be to great.   IMO service account should only be used if the developer wants to grant others access to their data.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it can be done by just simple email which will have access to all analytics accounts without service account .
Basically all I have done is creating google app and get credentials.json after grant an email analytics accounts permissions for reading & analyzing  and that is it!